# Vertically adjust example number in expex

Tags: vertical-alignment, right-to-left, expex

The `example number` in the `expex` package can be adjusted horizontally with the `numoffset` and `textoffset` commands, as documented on page 11 of the [documentation (links to PDF)](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/expex/expex-doc.pdf). But how can it be adjusted **vertically** (relative to the `\gla` baseline? The commands `aboveexskip` and `belowexskip` do not adjust the `example number` itself.

I would like the solution to work with both LTR and RTL languages.

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{expex} %gloss package

\lingset{everygla=\LARGE}

% to fix RTL example number going into margin
\makeatletter
\def\beginskip{\if@RTL\rightskip\else\leftskip\fi}
\def\ex@c{%
   \ex@setup
   \leavevmode
   \setbox\numbox=\hbox{\hskip\lingnumoffset\ep@actualexnoprint}%
   \epd@numright=\wd\numbox
   \ifcase\ep@textanchor
        \ep@settosum\beginskip\lingnumoffset\lingtextoffset
      \or
        \ep@settosum\beginskip\epd@numright\lingtextoffset
      \fi
   \llap{\hbox to\beginskip{\unhbox\numbox \hss}}
   \lingeveryex
   \latex@tagex
   \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent Left-to-right (LTR) example:

\ex\begingl
\gla Lorem ipsum //
\glb lorem ipsum //
\endgl\xe


\hfill Right-to-left (RTL) example:

\begin{hebrew}\ex\begingl
\gla לוראם איפסום //
\glb lorem ipsum //
\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new dimension key to ExPex and adjust the number using that. The following code works for `\ex` examples, but not `\pex` examples, since that code hasn't been included in your RTL/LTR fix.

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{expex} %gloss package



% to fix RTL example number going into margin
\makeatletter
% add a new dimension key numvoffset
\define@lingincdimenkeys{numoffset,textoffset,numvoffset}

\def\beginskip{\if@RTL\rightskip\else\leftskip\fi}
\def\ex@c{%
   \ex@setup
   \leavevmode
   \setbox\numbox=\hbox{\hskip\lingnumoffset\ep@actualexnoprint}%
   \epd@numright=\wd\numbox
   \ifcase\ep@textanchor
        \ep@settosum\beginskip\lingnumoffset\lingtextoffset
      \or
        \ep@settosum\beginskip\epd@numright\lingtextoffset
      \fi
   % add \lingnumvoffset to the example number output code
   \llap{\raise\lingnumvoffset\hbox to\beginskip{\unhbox\numbox \hss}}
   \lingeveryex
   \latex@tagex
   \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

% set the dimension key globally
\lingset{everygla=\LARGE,numvoffset=.5ex}
\begin{document}

\noindent Left-to-right (LTR) example:

\ex\begingl
\gla Lorem ipsum //
\glb lorem ipsum //
\endgl\xe


\hfill Right-to-left (RTL) example:

\begin{hebrew}\ex\begingl
\gla לוראם איפסום //
\glb lorem ipsum //
\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Excellent. I feel like this should exist in the `expex` package. Maybe I'll suggest it to John.

Comment: @AML Be my guest. It will need to be updated for the `\pex` examples anyway.